# How do I check whether a polynomial is separable over a function field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $K=\mathbb F_{673}(t)$, and consider the polynomial $f=t^3x^{2019}-t^4+2\in K[x]$.

I want to determine whether or not $f$ is separable.

So far, I've noticed that we can write $f$ as $(tx^{673})^{3}-t^4+2$, but I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Hint: compute $f'$.

Comment: Title: your field isn't finite. What do you find in your algebra lecture notes about this section?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Observe that $$f'=2019\,t^3x^{2018}=673(3t^3x^{2018})=0,$$ 
so what is $\gcd(f,f')$?